# Show that Graph is 5 or 4 colored

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I need to show, that the following graph is 5-colored or even better 4-colored. But I the only thing I got so far is 6-colored. The original graph is on the left, on the right is the result I have so far.

[image]

The problem is, that the (b) vertex alone has connections to 5 other vertices, so I need at least 6 colors. Am I right or am I missing something?

Comment: It's planar, therefore it's 4-colorable; no explicit coloring is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give different colors for vertices that are adjacent. So the vertices $e, d, c, f$ can have same color. You can see that two more colors will be needed to color all the vertices of this graph properly. So this is a $3$ colorable graph!